# Mapping international character to multiple options

Tags: elasticsearch

What I want to achieve is ability for people to search for individuals without being language aware, but not punishing those people, that are. What I mean is:

Given I build index:

1. Jorgensen
2. Jörgensen
3. Jørgensen

I want to be able allow such conversions:

1. ö to o
2. ö to oe
3. ø to oe
4. ø to oe

so if someone searches for:
QUERY      | RESULT(I include only ID's, but it would be full records in reality)

- Jorgensen  return - 1,2,3
- Jörgensen  return - 1,2
- Jørgensen  return - 1,3
- Joergensen return - 2,3

Starting with that I tried to create index analyzer and filter that:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "ö => o",
            "ö => oe"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that is invalid, because it tries to map to same character.

What ma I missing? Do I need multiple analyzers? Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you should investigate the [ICU folding token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.2/analysis-icu-folding.html)

Comment: @grlouk Have you investigated the ICU folding token filter like I suggested?

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work.If you can send me an example I would appreciate it.Thank you!

Comment: @Shawnas one thing I don't get, shouldn't users be able to retrieve all three docs regardless of whether they input `o`, `oe`, `ö` or `ø` ?

Comment: in my case, when he writes α he must get back all docs containing α and ά.

Comment: @Val I don't really want to mix ö and ø as they are quite different. Or at least give it a lower score, which should be fine. So ideally scoring should be - max for exact match, next one for phonetic right oe, next to english o, and then anything else that goes under fuzzy matching. Ideally when you search for Jörgensen it should be better to get Jørgensen than Mörgensen, but I am not too concerned by that

Comment: But if you want to allow `ö -> oe` and `ø -> oe` it still means that they are considered to be similar, aren't they?

Comment: @Val in a sense they are similar but not identical. Other look at it would be - lets say we have primary representation of word and alternative. for ö, would be primary ö and alternatives o, oe. What I would want to match anything that matches primary to primary, primary to alternative and alternative to primary representations, but alternative to alternative is quite weak assumption, that I am not to keen on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since custom mapping isn't enough in your case, as show comments above, let's play with your data and char normalization.
In your case, normalization using `unidecode` isn't enough due ø and oe conversions. Example:

```
import unicodedata
def strip_accents(s):
    return ''.join(
        c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
    )

body_matches = [
    u'Jorgensen',
    u'Jörgensen',
    u'Jørgensen',
    u'Joergensen',
]
for b in body_matches:
    print b,strip_accents(b)

>>>> Jorgensen Jorgensen
>>>> Jörgensen Jorgensen
>>>> Jørgensen Jørgensen
>>>> Joergensen Joergensen
```

So, we need a custom translation. By now I've only set those chars that you shown, but feel free to complete the list.

```
accented_letters = {
    u'ö' : [u'o',u'oe'],
    u'ø' : [u'o',u'oe'],
}
```

Then, we can normalize words and store them in a special property, `body_normalized` for instance, and index them as a field of your Elasticsearch records
Once they are inserted, you could perform two types of search:

1. exact search: User input isn't normalized and Elasticsearch query search against `body` field, that isn't normalized too.
2. simliar search. User input is normalized and we'll search againts 
   `body_normalized` field

Let's see an example

```
body_matches = [
    u'Jorgensen',
    u'Jörgensen',
    u'Jørgensen',
    u'Joergensen',
]
print "------EXACT MATCH------"
for body_match in body_matches:
    elasticsearch_query = {
        "query": {
            "match" : {
                "body" : body_match
            }
        }
    }
    es_kwargs = { 
        "doc_type"  : "your_type", 
        "index" : 'your_index', 
        "body" : elasticsearch_query
    }

    res = es.search(**es_kwargs)
    print body_match," MATCHING BODIES=",res['hits']['total']

    for r in res['hits']['hits']:
        print "-",r['_source'].get('body','')

print "\n------SIMILAR MATCHES------"
for body_match in body_matches:
    body_match = normalize_word(body_match)
    elasticsearch_query = {
        "query": {
            "match" : {
                "body_normalized" : body_match
            }
        }
    }
    es_kwargs = { 
        "doc_type"  : "your_type", 
        "index" : 'your_index', 
        "body" : elasticsearch_query
    }

    res = es.search(**es_kwargs)
    print body_match," MATCHING NORMALIZED BODIES=",res['hits']['total']

    for r in res['hits']['hits']:
        print "-",r['_source'].get('body','')
```

You can see a running example in [this notebook](https://github.com/xecgr/stackoverflow_answers/blob/master/Mapping%20international%20character%20to%20multiple%20options.ipynb)

Comment: thanks a lot for a great response. I will try verify everything.

Comment: although it is not producing exactly, after most of investigations it looks like approach I will have to take

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it quite bit more, so far I came up with following approach:

We cannot store multiple representations of data in one field. That does makes sense, so instead, like it was suggested, we store it in multiple representations of the same field in something like sub field. I did everything with [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) and/or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

---

Create index with following settings:

```
PUT surname
{
  "mappings": {
    "individual": { 
      "_all": { "enabled": false  }, 
      "properties": { 
        "id":    { "type": "integer"  }, 
        "name" : {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "not_folded",
            "fields": {
                "double": { 
                  "type":     "string",
                  "analyzer": "double_folder"
                },
                "single": { 
                  "type":     "string",
                  "analyzer": "folded"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "double_folder": {
          "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
          "filter" : [
            "icu_folding"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        },
        "folded": {
            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
            "filter": [
              "icu_folding"
            ]
          },
        "not_folded": {
            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "ö => oe"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in this case it stores all names in 3 different formats:

1. The way it was entered
2. Folded to multiple symbols where I want it to
3. Folded to single symbol

Number of shards one is important bit for testing, since having multiple shards doesn't work well where there is not enough data. More read in [Relevance is broken](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html)

then we can add test data to our index:

```
POST surname/individual/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 1}}
{ "id": "1", "name": "Matt Jorgensen"}
{ "index": { "_id": 2}}
{ "id": "2", "name": "Matt Jörgensen"}
{ "index": { "_id": 3}}
{ "id": "3", "name": "Matt Jørgensen"}
{ "index": { "_id": 4}}
{ "id": "4", "name": "Matt Joergensen"}
```

all that is left is to test if we get proper response:

```
GET surname/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields", 
      "query":    "Jorgensen",
      "fields": [ "name","name.double",   "name.single" ]
    }
  }
}
```